# TabBar is scrollable with extra empty space using NestedScrollView or CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a TabBar in Flutter. I expect the content to be scrolled if the content is exceeding the screen.

This is the existing problem I have:
[image]

I tried 2 different strategies:

One using the NestedScrollView:

```
return NestedScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollViewController,
                      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
                        return <Widget>[
                          SliverAppBar(
                            pinned: true,
                            floating: true,
                            leading: Container(),
                            titleSpacing: 0,
                            //expandedHeight: 80,
                            title: Text(
                              i18n.get(I18N_Constants.CLIENT_ACTIVITY_DETAIL_TITLE),
                              style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline6,
                            ),
                            forceElevated: boxIsScrolled,
                            centerTitle: true,
                            stretch: false,
                            bottom: TabBar(
                              tabs: <Widget>[
                                Tab(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.history, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.mail_outline,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                              controller: tabController,
                            ),
                          )
                        ];
                      },
                      body: TabBarView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new ClientSubscriptionDetailDescriptionTab(subscription),
                          new SubscriptionCalendarTab(subscription),
                          new SubscriptionDetailPhotosTab(subscription),
                          new SubscriptionDetailInboxTab()
                        ],
                        controller: tabController,
                      ),
                    );
```

And another using the `CustomScrollView`:

```
CustomScrollView(
                      shrinkWrap: false,
                        physics: RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics(),
                        controller: _scrollViewController,
                        slivers:  <Widget>[
                          SliverAppBar(
                            pinned: true,
                            flexibleSpace:Center(
                              child: Text(
                                i18n.get(I18N_Constants.CLIENT_ACTIVITY_DETAIL_TITLE),
                                style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline6,
                              ),
                            ),
                            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                            floating: true,
                            stretch: true,
                          ),
                          SliverPersistentHeader(
                            pinned: true,
                            floating: false,
                            delegate: SliverTabBarViewDelegate(
                              child: Container(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                                  child:TabBar(
                                tabs: <Widget>[
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_box, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.history, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.photo_camera, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                                  ),
                                  Tab(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.mail_outline,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                                controller: tabController,
                              )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SliverFillRemaining(
                                child: TabBarView(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new ClientSubscriptionDetailDescriptionTab(subscription),
                                      new SubscriptionCalendarTab(subscription),
                                      new SubscriptionDetailPhotosTab(subscription),
                                      new SubscriptionDetailInboxTab()
                                    ],
                                    controller: tabController,
                                  ),
                              ),
                        ]);
                  }
                })))
```

The result is the same in both. This is quite simple use case. Tabs. And obviously I could live with it, but gives not a professional behaviour.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Find the code here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75517